# EventView Appender Log4net using C#

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

I want clarification on root cause of an issue. I have integrated log4net library in my C# project. I have created appender using code. FileAppender, ConsoleAppender and AdoDotnetAppender was working fine but event

```
var eventViewAppender = new log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender();
eventViewAppender.Threshold = Level.Error;
eventViewAppender.LogName = "MyName";
eventViewAppender.ApplicationName = "MyName";
var layout = new log4net.Layout.PatternLayout()
{
    ConversionPattern = "%date{hh:mm:ss.fff} [%thread] %-5level - %message%newline"
};
eventViewAppender.Layout = layout;
layout.ActivateOptions();
log4net.Config.BasicConfigurator.Configure(eventViewAppender);
```

Then I took approach of having xml format configuration in app.config. I had below settings.

```
<appender name="EventLogAppender" type="log4net.Appender.EventLogAppender" >
  <applicationName value="MyApp" />
  <logName value="MyApp" />
  <threshold value="ERROR" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I think both configuration should work, but unfortunately second option works while first not. If anyone had encountered similar issue and fixed it, please do let me know resolution.

Comment: You need to call `ActivateOptions()` on the appender

Comment: I will try it, but As I mentioned I used file appender and db appender and there I have not called ActivateOption()